# Changing the code to run by button click won't work

Tags: c#

I'm working on a project for astrophotography using plate solving service from http://nova.astrometry.net/

I found AstrometryNetClient (here: https://github.com/elendil-software/AstrometryNetClient) I've managed to make it works for me with some changes in code, and it works just fine.

My problem is when I changed it to run when I click a button it does not work for some reason!

It stops at this line: `var res = client.Login();`

I think the problem is in the previous line: `var client = new Client(apiKey);`, because when I use F11 to check the code it shows
"Connected = false" which means that there is something wrong login in to http://nova.astrometry.net/api/

This is the original code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using software.elendil.AstrometryNet;
using software.elendil.AstrometryNet.Enum;
using software.elendil.AstrometryNet.Json;

namespace Test
{
  internal static class Program
  {
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      const string apiKey = "astrometrynetapikey";
      const string file = "test.fit";
      try
      {
        var client = new Client(apiKey);
        var res = client.Login();
        Console.WriteLine("Login : " + res.status);
        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new 
 CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;

        var uploadArguments = new UploadArgs 
     {publicly_visible = Visibility.n};
        var uploadResponse = client.Upload(file, uploadArguments);

        Task<SubmissionStatusResponse> 
submissionStatusResponse = client.GetSubmissionStatus(uploadResponse.subid, token);
        Task<JobStatusResponse> jobStatusResponse = 
client.GetJobStatus(submissionStatusResponse.Result.jobs[0], token);

        if (jobStatusResponse.Result.status.Equals(ResponseJobStatus.success))
        {
          var calibrationResponse = client.GetCalibration(submissionStatusResponse.Result.jobs[0]);
          var objectsInFieldResponse = client.GetObjectsInField(submissionStatusResponse.Result.jobs[0]);

          Console.WriteLine("\nRA : " + calibrationResponse.ra);
          Console.WriteLine("Dec : " + calibrationResponse.dec);
          Console.WriteLine("radius : " + calibrationResponse.radius);
          Console.WriteLine("");
          foreach (string obj in objectsInFieldResponse.objects_in_field)
          {
            Console.WriteLine(obj);
          }
        }
        else
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Status : " + jobStatusResponse.Result.status);
        }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
      }
      finally
      {
        Console.ReadKey();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be better to show us the code that *doesn't* work..

Comment: So, based on the original working code you have shown here, the problem in your non-working code using a button is.............somewhere to be found in the working code???   o.O?

Comment: What I did is actually copied the code from this line (const string apiKey = "astrometrynetapikey";)  and put it in a button click event

Comment: what did you do with the return value of the api call, the variable "client"?  It's needed for the login call.  Are you doing the login call inside the button click code?

Comment: Well, you could always single-step into the AstrometryNetClient code with the debugger (both the `Client` constructor as well as the `Login` method) to see what is going on there, and more imporantly, why and where things go awry...

Comment: I changed that with my apikey which works fine before changing the code to run by button click' it's "mmsbdisqwjmjophi" if you want to try

Comment: @elgonzo this actually what I did, when it reached this line: var client = new Client(apiKey);
it jumps to this line: catch (Exception e)

Comment: @LarsTech yes they are add by this page and not in my original code at the end of the code!

Comment: @astro, so you know what happens, no need to tell me. Look at the darn exception that has been caught. Be inquisitive. Do not expect the tools (like the debugger) to tell you what is wrong with your program, like you wouldn't expect a hammer to hammer a nail into a log all by itself. Like a hammer, the debugger is a tool to be used by your hands and your brain. Use the debugger to inspect the state of the program, variables, objects etc.. If there is an expection, look at it and figure out why it happened, and whether it is related to your problem...

Comment: @elgonzo:
it shows this message "Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: @astro, now, before posting the error message here, make an effort and read and try to understand it. After all, it (mostly) is plain English...

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution, It seems that I needed to install Newtonsoft.Json and it works just fine now.
Thanks everybody for your support!